# awk script- extract text between parenthesis

Tags: awk

I am tring to extract text between the first and its matching closing bracket in a file.

**Input**

```
CREATE MULTISET TABLE ABCD.EFGH,
NO FALLBACK,
NO BEFORE JOURNAL,
NO AFTER JOURNAL,
CHECKSUM = Default
( ABCK_SK      INTEGER         NOT NULL,
PRQ  VARCHAR(1024)           NOT NULL,
RST   DECIMAL (12,4)          NOT NULL,
LMN     CHAR(1)         NOT NULL,
OPQ      DATE            NOT NULL,
PQRS     DATE            NOT NULL,
TUV       INTEGER         NOT NULL,
WXY        INTEGER         NOT NULL
)  UNIQUE PRIMARY INDEX ABCK_PI (ABCK_SK)
;
```

**Expected Output**

```
ABCK_SK      INTEGER         NOT NULL,
PRQ  VARCHAR(1024)           NOT NULL,
RST   DECIMAL (12,4)          NOT NULL,
LMN     CHAR(1)         NOT NULL,
OPQ      DATE            NOT NULL,
PQRS     DATE            NOT NULL,
TUV       INTEGER         NOT NULL,
WXY        INTEGER         NOT NULL
```

I have written the following script for getting the line number and column number from where to where the text needs to be extracted, but i not able to actually print the output. Any suggetions would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

```
#!/bin/sh
nawk 'BEGIN{startln=0;j=0;i=0;endln=0;startchr=0;endchr=0} {
i=1; while( i<=NF ) {
if($i=="(" && startln==0 ){startchr=i; startln=NR} 
if($i==")"){j=j-1} 
if($i=="("){j=j+1} 
if(j==0){endchr=i;endln=NR;break} 
 i=i+1}} 
END{
print "startln="startln " startchr="startchr " endln="endln " endchr="endchr}' $1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A perl solution:

```
perl -e '$/=\1;
    while(<>) {
        if( /\)/ ) { $c -=1; exit unless $c }
        print if $c > 0;
        $c += /\(/
    }' input-file
```

Comment: This seems to be working perfectly for me.. I just need to embed it in my main scrpt and make sure it doesnt fail in the different types of input i give to it .. Thank you very much!! this had me completely stumped since yesterday morning..

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nice way to extract the data contained in the first matching parentheses:

```
sed -n -e '1,/(/s/[^(]*/foo/' -e '/(/,$p' input-file | m4 -D 'foo=$* m4exit(0)'
```

The sed replaces all text prior to the first open paren with the text `foo`, and then uses m4 with a macro named `foo` defined that simply outputs its first argument and then discards the remaining data.  `m4` has pretty robust parsing of parenthesis, so this should work for most cases.  (note that this will fail if your enclosed text contains the string `foo` followed by a `(`.  Choose some unique string other than `foo`.)

Comment: This does not seem to be working for me. <br> The output I am getting is <br> ABCK_SK INTEGER NOT NULL I has to run the command as follows as it was giving me command not found otherwise on solaris.<br> 
    sed -n -e '1,/(/s/[^(]*/foo/' -e '/(/,$p' input-file | /usr/ccs/bin/m4 -D 'foo=$1 /usr/ccs/bin/m4exit(1)'

Comment: Also one more thing to note is my input need not have the first ( as the first filed of a line eg, this could be **CHECKSUM = Default ( ABCK_SK INTEGER NOT NULL ,**

Comment: Sorry: you should use `$*` instead of `$1` in the definition of foo.  Edited.

Comment: Thank you .. This is working perfectly for me except for the fact that it wraps teh output into a single line. Could you help me get this into multiple lines as in the input?

Comment: `m4` is going to munge the whitespace around commas, and I don't think there is much that can be done to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Usage:
`awk -f foo.awk foo.txt`

**foo.awk**

```
BEGIN {
    ORS=""
    RS="[()]"
}

RT=="(" {
    s++;
    if (s>1) print $0 RT
}


RT==")" {
    s--;
    if (s==0) {
      print $0 "\n"
      exit
    } else {
      print $0 RT
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The script works for me if I have the opening and closing bracket as the first field in the lines. It however will not work if the brackets are in the middle of a line. I would need it to handle both cases.