# extracting text between two parentheses from a file in unix

Tags: shell, unix

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [awk script- extract text between parenthesis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11673754/awk-script-extract-text-between-parenthesis)

I am trying to extract text between two parentheses of a file in unix. Like Following

```
abc(

xyz,
abc,
mnr,
puc,

)
```

I tried using awk like:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS="abc"} {print $2}' file.txt
```

But this is not working.

Please help me in this regard

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11673754/awk-script-extract-text-between-parenthesis

Comment: This is fine but i need a single command to extract text

Comment: Those are single commands from a shell script perspective. The commands occupy multiple screen lines, but that is pure human interface. Restricting acceptable answers to single commands is suspicious anyway. Why?

Answer (score 3):

You could use `sed` to 'extract text' like this:

```
sed -n '/abc(/,/)/ { //d; /^\s*$/!p }' file
```

Results:

```
xyz,
abc,
mnr,
puc,
```

Explanation:

- Disable default printing with the `-n` switch
- Use the [range operator](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-29) to 'select' a pattern between two patterns `abc(` and `)`
- `//d` deletes the selected patterns: `abc(` and `)`.
- And `/^\s*$/!p` tells sed to print anything except empty lines.

---

or with `awk`:

```
awk '/abc\(/ { r=""; f=1 } f && !/^(abc\(|\)|\s*)$/ { r = (r ? r ORS : "") $0 } /\)/ { if (f) print r; f=0 }' file
```

Results:

```
xyz,
abc,
mnr,
puc,
```

Comment: It works correctly using GNU `sed`. What flavor of `sed` are you using? A simpler solution would be: `sed -n '/abc(/,/)/ { //d; /^$/!p }' file`. Not sure if this would solve your problem. Also, what is your error message? Do you get one?

Comment: Steve I am using GNU sed version 4.1.2 and This is not showing any error message and there are some more lines are present in the same file with () parantheses

Comment: I would find the lack of an error message quite concerning - your installation of `sed` may be broken. I've tested the above using `GNU sed version 4.2.1`, but it should definitely work with version 4.1.2.

Comment: i am not sure about whether sed that used in my unix is broken is there any other way to get the output

Comment: @lakshmi: I've added a solution using `awk`. Please let me know how it goes. HTH.

Comment: Steve is it not giving any output i mean the awk

Comment: @lakshmi: Either your whole system is broken, or the file you're working on is not representative of that described in your question. I would check the file's contents. Do any of the commands above work on the sample file described?

Answer (score 1):

way 1:

if there are always empty lines after `abc(` and before `)`:

```
awk -vRS="" '/abc\($/{f=1;next};/\)/{f=0}f' file
```

way 2:

if you are not sure about the empty lines:

```
awk '/abc\($/{f=1;next;} /^ *\) *$/{f=0}f' file
```

note, in way 2, some cases won't work. for example, there is nested "`)`" line in your abc(...) block. but you could test it. based on the given input in your question. both work.

Comment: Kent there are some lines before the following block bc(

xyz,
abc,
mnr,
puc,

) the way 1 and way2 are not working